# How to add csv row to array in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to import a csv file. Take the first row(with headers) and add it to an array in powershell. 
`$csv = Import-CSV "test.csv"
$array = @()`

Comment: You may specify what problem you'd like to solve or why you want to do what you want to do. Because importing a CSV creates an array by default. When you run `$csv.GetType()` after your import you will see.

Answer (score 1):

Would you need an explicit conversion to array when import-csv is giving you a nice enumerable array of *System.Object* instances?

When you use **import-csv** , PowerShell will read the header row and give you back an array of custom objects. Each of these objects will have properties which match the Header column.

**Example of test.csv**

```
Id,FirstName
1,Name001
2,Name002
```

**Results after import-csv**

You can iterate through the collection as shown below

```
$csv = Import-CSV "test.csv"
foreach($item in $csv)
{
    $msg=("Id={0}  , Name={1}" -f $item.Id, $item.FirstName)
    Write-Host $msg
}
#Add the first item to your own array
$arrMy=@()
$arrMy+=$csv[0]
$arrMy
```

**Output**

```
Id=1  , Name=Name001
Id=2  , Name=Name002


Id FirstName
-- ---------
1  Name001
```

**MSDN**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-6

**Getting deeper - what does import-csv actually return?**

It returns an array with N objects of type *System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject*. Here N=no of rows in the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking here, but it looks to me that you want to get the **headers** of a CSV file as array:  (*Take the first row(with headers) and add it to an array in powershell*)

If that is the case, here's a small function that can do that for you:

```
function Get-CsvHeaders {
    # returns an array with the names of the headers in a csv file in the correct order
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'ByDelimiter')]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Leaf})]
        [string]$Path,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [ValidateSet ('ASCII', 'BigEndianUnicode', 'Default', 'OEM', 'Unicode', 'UTF32', 'UTF7', 'UTF8')]
        [string]$Encoding = $null,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'ByDelimiter')]
        [char]$Delimiter = ',',

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'ByCulture')]
        [switch]$UseCulture
    )
    $splatParams = @{ 'Path' = $Path }
    switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
        'ByDelimiter' { $splatParams.Delimiter  = $Delimiter; break }
        'ByCulture'   { $splatParams.UseCulture = $true; break }
    }
    if ($Encoding)    { $splatParams.Encoding = $Encoding }

    $data = Import-Csv @splatParams -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $data[0].PSObject.properties.name
}
```

Usage:

```
$headersArray = Get-CsvHeaders -Path 'test.csv'
```